# Included source of javascript via PHP, onmousemove event, function is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I have i php require:

```
if ($infoSystem['timeout'] == 1) {require_once 'set_timeout.php';}
```

function in set_timeout.php which invoke error:

```
// Reset timers.
    function ResetTimers() {
        clearTimeout(warningTimer);
        clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
        StartTimers();
        $("#timeout").dialog(\'close\');
    }
```

output error:

```
ResetTimers is not defined on line: xxx
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: <body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">

Comment: You have to write js function before you add it in event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write js function before you add it in event. – Knase Feb 20 '15 at 22:29